# listView- how can you make each item clickable

Tags: listview, android-activity

I have a list of items on ListView that when one is pressed I would like to open a new activity. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This question is potentially easily google-able but I'll put the code here anyway.

ListView can have a listener attached that listens to clicks of its list items:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            YourItemType item = (YourItemType)parent.getAdapter().get(position);
            YourInfo info = item.getInfo();
            Intent intent; //instantiate intent here with info
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```